# How do I prevent MacOS terminal from starting multiple shell processes

Tags: terminal, zsh, login, macos

I've started using Z shell on MacOS Big Sur. I changed the default shell via `chsh -s /bin/zsh`. When I start the Terminal I see two processes running:

```
$ ps
CMD
-zsh
/bin/zsh
```

I also see the following output when I start the Terminal program (from Applications):

```
Last login: xxxx
<USER>@macbook ~ % /bin/zsh
<USER>@macbook ~ %
```

I've moved all of my `~/.*rc` files to a backup directory and continue to observe this behavior. Furthermore, I changed my default shell back to bash via `chsh -s /bin/bash` and continue to see similar behavior:

```
Last login: xxxx

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
macbook:~ <USER>$ /bin/zsh
<USER>@macbook ~ % ps
CMD
-bash
/bin/zsh
```

At this point, I'm not sure what to try next. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it you typing `/bin/zsh` at the `macbook:~ <USER>$` prompt?

Comment: No, this line shows up "automatically" when I start the Terminal: `macbook:~ <USER>$ /bin/zsh`

Comment: What terminal application aru you using and has that been configured to execute a command upon startup?

Comment: I'm using MacOS Terminal (2.11). Also, it turns out that I (previously) configured my profile to run a shell command on startup. To find this, I navigated to Terminal => Preferences => Profiles => Shell => Run Command (un-check box). This appears to have fixed my issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this behavior was due to one of the profiles I had configured in the MacOS Terminal application. Navigating to the settings page and un-checking the "Run Command" box fixed my problem:

```
Terminal => Preferences => Profiles => Shell => Startup Section 
=> Run Command (un-check box)
```